# Как сделать авторизацию на сайте через вк

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация, регистрация

По описанному [тут](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) методу я не получаю никакого постоянного аутентификатора пользователя (id или типо этого), то что я могу записать в бд при регистрации, а потом сверять при входе пользователя на сайт. Так как регистрировать пользователя с помощью вк?
Сайт пишу на python (django)

Comment: Есть довольно хорошая [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/48565/) по этой теме с использованием [`social-auth-app-django`](https://pypi.org/project/social-auth-app-django/)

Comment: @nomnoms12 меня смущает то, что ей 7 лет

Comment: За это время не так много поменялось. Базовые вещи остаются базовыми. В конце концов, самую актуальную информацию можно найти в [документации пакета](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html).